# $this->_forward() e Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend, framework

Senhores,

No uso do `$this->_forward()` no *Zend Framework 1* nós damos um redirecionamento para o `controller` e `action` que queremos. No meu caso isso não está funcionamento bem na seguinte situação.

Fiz uma consulta, quero que após `deletar` um registro ele suma e já redirecione para mesma tela onde estava a consulta.

Outra coisa é que o `forward` faz com que a `url` não mude.... ele redireciona, mas a `url` fica com parâmetro do registro `... /apagar?idRegistro=56`.

**Action**:

```
public function apagarAction()
    {

        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

        $idTel = $this->_getParam('idRegistro');

        $modTel = new Sca_Model_Telefone('sca');
        $idRegistro = $modTel->getAdapter()->quoteInto('idTelefone = ?', $idTel);

        $modTel->delete($idRegistro);

        $this->_forward('consultar', 'index', 'sistel');
        $this->view->deletado = "Registro deletado com sucesso.";

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

O funcionamento do `_forward()` é esse mesmo. Ele redireciona para outro *controller* ou *action* após receber a requisição. A URL continua a mesma porque ele não cria um *request* novo, assim como faz o método `redirect()` que, este sim, lança um `header()`.

Sugiro utilizar o `redirect()` mesmo ou implementar a exclusão em AJAX, se você quiser algo mais rápido e interativo.

Se você utilizar `redirect()` e quiser exibir mensagens ao usuário, pode utilizar o "FlashMessenger", que tem exatamente a função de enviar mensagens ao *request* futuro.

No *controller*:

Setar uma mensagem:

```
$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Mensagem');
```

Recuperar mensagem setada anteriormente:

```
$this->_helper->FlashMessenger->getMessages();
```